# Anisble error: "Failed to update apt cache:..."

Tags: apt, updates, ansible

I'm working on an Ansible project in the cloud and got this error. In my config-server.yml file, this is the part where the job fails, as reported by CircleCi:

```
pre_tasks:
    - name: "wait 600 seconds for target connection to become reachable/usable."
      wait_for_connection:

    - name: "install python for Ansible."
      apt:
        name: python3
        state: latest
        update_cache: yes
```

> fatal: [3.86.214.200]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to
> update apt cache: W:Updating from such a repository can't be done
> securely, and is therefore disabled by default., W:See apt-secure(8)
> manpage for repository creation and user configuration details., E:The
> repository 'http://*********.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan
> Release' no longer has a Release file., W:Updating from such a
> repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by
> default., W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user
> configuration details., E:The repository
> 'http://*********.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates Release'
> no longer has a Release file., W:Updating from such a repository can't
> be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default., W:See
> apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration
> details., E:The repository
> 'http://*********.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-backports
> Release' does not have a Release file., W:Updating from such a
> repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by
> default., W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user
> configuration details., E:The repository
> 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security Release' no longer
> has a Release file."}

How do I solve `Failed to update apt cache...`?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTjYB.png)

Answer (score 0):

eoan is Ubuntu 19.10 End of Support since 17. Juli 2020. no more updates. your message indicates the repositories have been removed. Upgrade to an supportetd version.

Comment: there's a plethora of other reasons and bugs that can also trigger this.